# How to test ajax with Capybara + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

Guys.

I'm trying test using Rails 3.1.1 + Rspec + Capybara my form that use AJAX, but no success. Would be the correct when the field postal_code lost focus the street would be loaded, but this does not happen. This is source code of the my test: [source](https://gist.github.com/1920832)

Answer (score 2):

What kind of driver are you using with Capybara? For javascript - enabled integration testing you need to use, for example: `selenium`.

Comment: As far as I know: no. By default Capybara is running on rack.